# How to create a new string according to a user's input string

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Excel experts, How can I create a new string according to a user's input string

Say in one cell, user input a string '15324', and the mapping rule is:

```
'1'->'A'
'2'->'B'
'3'->'C'
'4'->'D'
'5'->'E'
```

How to automatically generate 'AECBD' in target cell.

It will be best if we only use EXCEL's functions and no VBA or other scripts.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: how many characters does the user enter? With formulas, you would need to do a lookup for each character and concatenate the results. That will be a long and ugly formula because there is no way to loop over an array in a formula.

Comment: not many, around 10 or so, I could put the mapping table somewhere to use LOOKUP. the hard part for me is how to loop the char in that input string...

Comment: Just to confirm, you weren't interested in a solution that only works in Google Sheets?

Comment: Hi AdamL, preferably work both in google spreadsheet and EXCEL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution that will only work in Google Sheets, so doesn't achieve your preference of working in Excel as well.

Assumes your lookup table is in C:D (although that table may be hardcoded into the formula if you wish). Will return an #N/A error if any character is not found in that lookup table.

`=ArrayFormula(CONCATENATE(VLOOKUP(MID(A1,ROW(OFFSET($A$1,,,LEN(A1),1)),1),C:D&"",2,0)))`

Note: the $A$1 in the formula must stay as that reference (or at least, a cell in row 1).

Answer (score 0):

With no option to loop, any formula will carry a great deal of repetition.

To make the formula less wordy, create a named range, call it "Alphabet" and assign it the string value `="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQSTUVWXYZ"`

The following model can be extended to more characters. Input can be number or a string and can be five or less characters:

```
=MID(Alphabet,MID(A1,1,1),1)&
IF(LEN(A1)>=2,MID(Alphabet,MID(A1&"",2,1),1),"")&
IF(LEN(A1)>=3,MID(Alphabet,MID(A1&"",3,1),1),"")&
IF(LEN(A1)>=4,MID(Alphabet,MID(A1&"",4,1),1),"")&
IF(LEN(A1)>=5,MID(Alphabet,MID(A1&"",5,1),1),"")
```

Comment: thanks, Excel really dont allow us to loop a string?

Comment: No. There is no looping in formulas. You need VBA for that.

Answer (score 0):

You might try:

```
=CHAR(LEFT(A1,1)+64)&CHAR(MID(A1,2,1)+64)&CHAR(MID(A1,3,1)+64)&CHAR(MID(A1,4,1)+64)&CHAR(MID(A1,5,1)+64)
```

and extend to 8 characters if desired (and all are present).

Answer (score 0):

If in A1 is the value: 1234332

The length of the string in A1 can be any.

Put in B1 the formula: =arrayformula(join("";char(mid(A1;row(offset($A$1;0;0;len(A1);1));1)+96)))